# making iris's color selector dissappear when it's not in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" /><br />
```

My Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#color-picker').iris();
    $('#color-picker').blur(function() {
        $('#color-picker').iris('hide');
    });
    $('#color-picker').focus(function() {
        $('#color-picker').iris('show');
    });
});
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vdmw1knL/3/

Without the blur / focus stuff if you click on the text input the color picker will appear and never go away. With the blur / focus stuff if you click on the color picker it'll appear but then it'll go away if you actually select a color.

I want the color picker to go away if either the text input that it's attached to or the html composing itself go out of focus. Clicking on a color within the color picker ought not make it go away. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make it do this. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by `html composing itself `?

Comment: @LuckySoni - the HTML that is being used to create the color picker. It starts off with `div class="iris-picker iris-mozilla iris-border" style="display: block"` etc per "Inspect This Element".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do by checking whether you clicked inside or outside the color picker like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#color-picker').iris();
  $('#color-picker').blur(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$(document.activeElement).closest(".iris-picker").length)
        $('#color-picker').iris('hide');
      else 
        $('#color-picker').focus();
    }, 0);
  });
  $('#color-picker').focus(function() {
    $('#color-picker').iris('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/Iris/master/src/iris.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" />
<br />
<div style="position: relative" id="#test">zzz</div>
```

Comment: Rather than using setTimeout to update the activeElement, you can use information from the blur event: `$(e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget).closest(....`

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#color-picker').iris();
  $('#color-picker').focus(function() {
    $('#color-picker').iris('show');
    $('.iris-picker').addClass('active');
  });


  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    var clicked = $(event.target),
      $iris = $('.iris-picker');

    if ($iris.hasClass('active') && !clicked.is('.iris-picker') && !clicked.is('#color-picker')) {
      $('#color-picker').iris('hide');
      $iris.removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Automattic/Iris/master/src/iris.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://automattic.github.io/Iris/javascripts/iris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='color-picker' value="#bada55" />
<br />
<div style="position: relative" id="#test">zzz</div>
```